# how to redirect different types of pages for different users after login in django

Tags: django, django-registration, django-users, django-login, django-custom-user

I have created two different types of users - truck & company using Django. Here is my registration page of a user [Registration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB8Ac.png)

After registering, the data about whether the user is a truck or company will go to the database.

In my login page, [image: Login Page] only EmailID and Password are to be entered.

I would like to know how a user with a unique EmailID can redirects to a valid page based on the type of user.

I assume, Authentication and getting the data from POST request(in views.py ) to my login page isn't working properly. Please, someone help me fixing this.

here's my code:

views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
def login_view(request):
    title = "Login"
    if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST.get('email', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_type = form.cleaned_data['Label']
        if user_type == 'Truck':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post_load/')
        elif user_type == 'Company':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/live_deal/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form' : form, 'title': title})
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
```

forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(auth.forms.AuthenticationForm):

email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"),widget=forms.EmailInput)
CHOICES= (('Truck', 'Truck'),('Company', 'Company'),)
Label = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, label='Label', widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

login.html:

```html
{%extends "registration/header.html"%}
{% block content %}
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your email and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action = "." >{%csrf_token%}
<div class="panel panel-default login">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4'>
                    <table border="0">
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 

        <tr><th><label for="id_user" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email:</label></th><td>{{ form.email }}</td></tr> </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 



        <tr><th><label for="id_password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password:</label></th><td>{{ form.password }}</td></tr> </div> 

    </table> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"/>
                                Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group last">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                            Sign in</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" /> 
                            <label class="col-sm-offset-3">
                     <a href="#">Forget Password? </a>
                </label> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                Not Registered? <a href="/register/">Register</a></div>

</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better way to check that radio field in your views:-

```
user_type = form.cleaned_data['Label']
if user_type == 'truck':
   # send the user to truck page
else:
   # send the user to company page
```

A few more things - you don't really need to call that clean() method once you validate using is_valid() and you should move that authenticate() thing inside that POST section.

Comment: I edited the code as you suggested @CODEkid. 

But, when I am logging with valid credentials that I have created using my registration page, authentication isn't working. It raising an error "Your email and password didn't match. Please try again." which I have created in my login.html if user details aren't valid.

Comment: Have you overridden the authenticate() method? It takes 'username' and 'password' as kwargs.

Comment: I am new to Django bro. I am just copy pasting everything i wanted. Could you please help me solving this. And I have overridden the authenticate method() in my customuser creation form as username field = 'email'

Comment: Alright! You're storing user's email as its username, right? In that case, just use `auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password) `. Also make sure the user has `is_active` field set to True.

Comment: Where should i put, is_active = True?

Comment: All you gotta change is pass the value of 'email' form field as 'username' to authenticate().

Comment: still it's not working. It showing the same error.

Comment: Try printing those errors in the console using `print form.errors.items()` if the form does not validate.

Comment: I think The error is not because of the Django code. I created the HTML page in such a way that if the user is valid he should be logged in to a particular page. If the user isn't valid, in the login page itself it raises - "Your email and password didn't match. Please try again."

Comment: I realize that the name of the choices you're using in form starts with caps (Truck and Company),  and you're comparing - `user_type == 'truck'`. Change it to `if user_type == 'Truck'`

Comment: No result, still same. Should i provide some more info?